# QML, code once, deploy twice

Tags: qt, user-interface, mobile, qml, desktop

I am creating an application in QML. Initially it was for desktop use only, but I decided to cover Android devices too.

The problem I'm struggling with is how to handle different platforms. For now, I have a separate class that provides informations about screen ratio, platform(mobile, desktop) orientation etc.

What is the best approach to provide UX closest to native, for each platform?

How to handle situations like this?

**Mobile**

- StackView with 2 pages
- ListView taking entire screen space
- Clicking on object in the ListView navigates to the second page with
  additional info

**Desktop**

- No StackView
- ListView taking only 300 pixels
- Additional info about currently selected element on the list should
  be visible in TextArea next to ListView

Designing scalable UI, based on calculated screen ratio or pixel density for a given device is one solution. But, this kind of mobile-ish interface looks pretty bad on desktop. Can you imagine Android Gmail app running on PC?

The solution I see is to place as much logic as possible into C++ and create lightweight layouts for both mobile and desktop platforms in QML.

What is, in your opinion best way to target multiple devices. Should I create scalable UI for mobile and use it on desktop and just 'deal with it' or should I sacrifice more time and create UI for each platform so that it will be user friendly everywhere?

Comment: May I suggest you look into Google's Material Design? Following that design system will give you some tools to decide what to do with different platforms/form factors. There is a nice library, qml-material, that provides already lots of functionality, components and styles. https://github.com/papyros/qml-material if not that, try to embrace any other solid design system before implementing your own

Comment: I've upvoted your question at least for its title :)

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create scalable UI for mobile and use it on desktop and just 'deal with it' or should I sacrifice more time and create UI for each platform so that it will be user friendly everywhere?

This question is quite subjective, and we haven't seen the UI in question, but in my opinion, you should sacrifice more time and create a decent UI for desktop and mobile. This is assuming that the desktop version of your application has enough content and/or features to warrant it.

> The solution I see is to place as much logic as possible into C++ and create lightweight layouts for both mobile and desktop platforms in QML.

This is the right approach. QML is super easy to write, and super easy to maintain as long as you keep it simple. Qt Quick Controls learned this the hard way, and this is why [Qt Quick Controls 2](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/31/qt-quick-controls-for-embedded/) are being created: to use as much C++ and as little JavaScript, expensive bindings, `Loader`s etc. as possible.